# Express session data is not removed from Mongo store when destroy is invoked in Production

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

I am facing an issue with logout functionality of my application.

**Problem**

Calling req.session.destroy does not remove the session data from the Sessions MongoDB collection in **Production only**.

The request hits the server, logout method runs, no error is returned from destroy function, running console.log on the session shows it is empty, yet on page refresh the user is still logged in, and checking db.sessions.find() shows the session data untouched.

I presume the subdomain setup has something to do with this, as local works as expected. I just can't figure out what this is as the app otherwise functions fine.

**Key packages in use**

- express-session
- connect-mongo
- cors

The functionality works fine locally (API and React app both run on localhost, just different ports).

Production is setup so that

- api.mydomain.com is the Node server with Express API & Mongo db.
- app.mydomain.com is a React app that sends requests to the API.

**server.js - important part**

```
    //use sessions for tracking logins
var sessionData = {
    name: 'secure_name', // for testing
    secret: 'secure_secret', // for testing
    resave: true,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    cookie: {
        "maxAge": (1000 * 60 * 60 * 7), // 7 days.
        secure: false,
        path: '/',
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN
    }
};

// Setup session with config and make the app use it.
var sessionMiddleware = session(sessionData);
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

...
// User - Logout.
app.get('/api/users/logout', user.logout);
```

**user.logout method**

```
// Logout user.
exports.logout = (req, res, next) => {

    // Only if there is an active session.
    if (req.session) {

        // delete session object
        req.session.destroy(error => {

            req.session = null;
            if (error) return next(error);

            res.send({ logout: true })
        });
    }
}
```

**React logout method request**

```
        // Logout - end this user session.
    @action logout() {

        // Destroy session.
        return axios.get(config.url + 'api/users/logout', {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution to my problem. Posting here in case anyone else stumbles upon a similar issue.

The GET request sent to the server didn't include any credentials, as by default this is set to false.

The solution was to explicitly set "with-credentials" to true in the request, as illustrated below:

```
        // Logout - end this user session.
@action logout() {

    // Destroy session.
    return axios.get(config.url + 'api/users/logout', {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true
        })
```